# how to create a reusable function available across apps in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following function that I call in all of my apps and in almost every view function.

```
def get_customer(request):
    return request.user.customer
```

I want to have one function that I can  call from every app or even have this value available in every view.

How can I do this?

Comment: The way I usually do it is create a `utils.py` file under the main app, and put all the common functions in there. Then use that in other apps by... `from mainapp.utils import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure how you want to use, but if you need something reusable mostly for templates (as views handle logic differently depending on the request) then you can proceed with the bellow method, if you need something reusable in different parts of the stack, then a simple function / class that is imported in the appropriate parts is just enough.
If you want to inject a reusable var inside the view, then a context.processor is the good place to have this kind of logic.

create a context_processors.py file (name does not matter, but it's always nice to follow Django naming schemes for readability) in one of your apps (most likely the app that deals mostly with the logic, probably the customer app).

In your context_processors.py:

```
def get_customer(request):
    try:
        customer = request.user.customer
        return {'customer': customer}
    except:
        """
        You need to always return a dictionary, even empty.
        """
        return {}
```

Enable the context processor, in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS (settings.py):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contry.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
    "yourapp.context_processors.get_customer"
)
```

THen in your template you can access this:

```
{% if customer %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Mind though that is wise to create names that wont conflict with other parts, so it would be better to name the passed element
to something more unique like myappscustomer.

If you are using CBV's (Class Based Views) you could create a Mixin and reuse it:

```
class MyCustomerMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyCustomerMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user:
            try:
                context['mycustomer'] = self.request.user.customer
            except:
                pass
        return context
```

Then use it in your View:

```
class SomeView(MyCustomerMixin, TemplateView):
    ....
```

Comment: This would inject into the template context. Instead, the OP was saying to reuse the function in the view. Aside from that, good and detailed answer.

Comment: Correct but I can't know what exactly he wants with no further description from his side, I imagined he wants to use that in templates, other than that he could just define the function centrally and import it where needed :)

Comment: Yeah, agreed, note this in the answer to make it complete. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, added the clarification, if you feel it needs more just let me know :)